# auto switch cases from *.php file

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

I am trying to get files from folder and adding them to switch case, is it possible?

If it is possible, i want to use only file name in case but when i echo them they are like "/etc/folder/otherfolder/filename.php" this...

I tried to trim and explode them but i cant do that.

```
$files = glob("pages/" . "/*.*");

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {            
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($files[$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    echo $files[$i] . '<br/>';
    switch($section){
        case $files[$i]:
            include_once $files[$i];
            break;
        default:
            include_once $files[0];
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: No clue what you are trying to do here. What is `$section`? And why do you need to treat the first entry of the array differently from the others? Please describe what you actually want to _achieve_ here.

Comment: ı am trying get all my static php files to use case...

Comment: That doesn’t explain it any better.

Comment: i am trying to get my all static php files with dynamicly using switch case

Comment: Repeating the same nonsense does not make it any clearer. Please explain what you are trying to achieve here - without even mentioning the word “switch”.

Comment: i have folders which includes static php files, i want to link them all dynamicly...

Comment: And in what way does that require that some of those scripts are treated differently than others?

Comment: Use basename($files[$i]) u will get only the filename.
EX:
$path = "/home/httpd/html/index.php";
$file = basename($path);         // $file is set to "index.php"

Comment: no it is not, i want to use only include

Comment: Your $section variable contains only filename right ie like filename.php. correct?

Comment: i want to use it filename but without .php...

Comment: And you want to include only the matched file right?

Comment: yes but from folder with case in include all...

Answer (score 1):

Try this mostly this is what you are looking for:

```
    $files = glob("pages/" . "/*.*");
                $file_found=0;     //found variable
                for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {

                    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($files[$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                    $file = basename($files[$i]);         // $file is set to "example.php"
                    $file = basename($files[$i], ".php"); // $file is set to only "example"
                    echo $file . '<br/>';

                    switch($section){
                        case $file:         //campares only filename without extension
                            include_once $files[$i];  //includes using the full path
                        $found=1;  //case matched
                        break;
                        case "all":
                            foreach (glob("pages/*.php") as $filename) //loops every file and include each one
                            {
                                include $filename;
                            }
                        $found=1; //case matched
                        break;  

                    }
                } 
               if(!$found)
                  include_once($files[$0]);
```

Comment: yes this is what i want, so much thank you it is working but default is coming every case page...

Comment: As your switch is inside the loop the switch is getting one match parameter and all other parameters are unmatched so its executing default case.

Comment: Remove default case & use a $found variable. I have edited the answer, try it and if works then accept the answer.

Comment: Oh what is the problem?